# How to get data between @ to @ using regular expression in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

This is my code which is below

```
$(".xyz").contextMenu({
menu: 'myMenu'
}, function(action, el, pos) {
var str= $(el).text();

    var result = ""; 

alert(
    'Element text: ' + str + '\n\n'+result+'\n' 
     );
 });
```

str's value may be like below

```
 str ="201-201 abc xyz 123";
```

Here str's length is not fixed and I want to separate to str (for example, **201-201 abc xyz** and **123**) ,here first and last separate part length   is not fixed. Here result will be from last to still before blankspace (which is 123)

Here will be result is 123( result =123 , result length is not fixed);

How can i solve it?
Or

```
if str ="201-201 abc xyz @123";
```

then How can i result from @ to still last.

Or

```
if str ="201-201 abc xyz @123@";
```

then How can i result between @ and @.

Result lenght is not fixed (which may be 1 or 12 or 123 or...)

Please help me? any suggestion ?

Comment: Here's a good link to start http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/jquery-exec-compile-regex/

Comment: You can just use `.split('@')` and grab the appropriate array item. Regex isn't always the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not expert in regex ,Please specify from any my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just:

```
str ="201-201 abc xyz @123@";

var parts = str.split('@');

console.log(parts[1]); // 123
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NmwEN/)**

---

To check both case, you can do:

```
str ="201-201 abc xyz 123";
if(str.indexOf('@') != -1) {
    var parts = str.split('@');
    console.log(parts[1]); 
} else {
    var parts = parseInt(str.match(/\d+$/), 10);
    console.log(parts); 
}
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NmwEN/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: How about the strings not containing `@`?

Comment: @Jørgen you need to use regex, wait I will update my answer shortly

Comment: :) To avoid null pointers here, you should split on whitespace and replace the `@` in the last element of the array.

Comment: Thanks but i want to display to alert How to give which variable ?

Comment: I am so sorry without understand nicely , Your are absolutely right. I am very happy , I have got my desired result from your first code. Thanks a lot ............. Can you help me to increase my reputation .

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
"@([^@]*)@"
```

for the regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

To match the last word in a string, skipping `@`, you could use this expression:

```
var result = '201-201 abc xyz @123@'.match(/(.*)\s[@|](.*?)[@|]$/)
console.log(result[2]);
```

`result` should be an array like this:

```
["201-201 abc xyz @123@", "201-201 abc xyz", "123"]
```

Here, index 0 matches the whole string, whereas index 1 and 2 match the first and second part of it.

---

**Edit**
To match the last word in a string, skipping `@`, you could use try this:

```
var result = '201-201 abc xyz @123@'.match(/.*\s(.*?)$/);
var lastWord = result[1];
lastWord.replace(/@/g, '');
console.log(lastWord);
```

Comment: The result should be an array like this: `["201-201 abc xyz @123@", "123"]`. Your result should be at index 1. Do you also need to first part of the string?

Comment: No, first part is not need, I want to print result (123) , i use this result anohter part.

Comment: Thanks a lot work is fine. But if i use str instead of '201-201 abc xyz @123@' (which var result = str .match(/(.*)\s[@|](.*?)[@|]$/)) then it is not working

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I should have used () instead of [] in the expression, but that would make the result quite complicated. I've edited the answer with a simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Can you help me to increase  my reputation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last part of the string this might be a solution for you

```
// Sample string
str = "201-201 abc xyz 123"

// Split the string into parts separated by <space>.
parts = str.split(" ")
// Parts is now an array containing ["201-201", "abc", "xyz", "123"]
// so we grab the last element of the array (.length -1)
last = parts[parts.length-1]
```

If you want the last *numeric* part of the string

```
// Match using regular expressions. () is a "capture group" \d means digits
// and + means we want 1 or more. the $ is a symbol representing the end of the string.
// The expression can be read as; "capture 1 or more digits at the end of the string".
matches = str.match(/(\d+)$/)
// Matches will be stored in an array, with the contents ["123", "123"]
// The first part is the fully matched string, the last part is the captured group.
numeric = matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but result not comes successful, For your last or below numeric part's result will come null

Comment: In that case you might want `matches[0]`, did I under stand you correctly when I assumed `@` was just placeholders? If the `@` is part of the string I'll need to change the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot , Can you help me to increase  my reputation?